# Color of OverFlowButton in WPF toolbar

Tags: .net, wpf, button, overflow, toolbar

There was a problem. When I change the background color of WPF toolbar Overflow Button in the right corner does not change color. How to fix it?

Example:
[alt text http://biztimes.ru/toolbar.jpg](http://biztimes.ru/toolbar.jpg)

Comment: I'm a newbie in WPF. Can you post code on how you did it, antongladchenko? A few lines of code would be better for getting a quick start. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overflow button unfortunately has a fixed background. More precisely, it is set to a static value in the default template. See [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f8e3c903-5c82-46ec-a065-9a75d9f79b75/) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) if you want to get a copy of them. Or [This tool from Chris Sells](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/2091)

In the template, you'll see a ToggleButton, that is used to show/hide the overflow panel. This is the one to change to have the effect that you are looking for.

So, the answer to your question is that you need to include the full style of the toolbar in your XAML and change the background of the button to be the same as the rest of the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem you described above. My solution is the following:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WPF.Controls
{
    public class ToolBar : System.Windows.Controls.ToolBar
    {
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            var overflowPanel = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel") as ToolBarOverflowPanel;
            if (overflowPanel != null)
            {
                overflowPanel.Background = OverflowPanelBackground ?? Background;
                overflowPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            }
        }

        public Brush OverflowPanelBackground
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML sample:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WPF.Controls">

<ToolBarTray Background="White">
    <wpf:ToolBar Background="Pink" OverflowPanelBackground="Peru" Band="1" BandIndex="1" Width="50">
        <Button Content="Cut" />
        <Button Content="Copy" />
        <Button Content="Paste" />
    </wpf:ToolBar>
    <wpf:ToolBar Background="Aqua" Band="2" BandIndex="1" Width="70">
        <Button Content="Undo" />
        <Button Content="Redo" />
    </wpf:ToolBar>
    <wpf:ToolBar OverflowPanelBackground="Yellow" Band="2" BandIndex="2" Width="100">
        <Button Content="Paint"/>
        <Button Content="Spell"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Button Content="Save"/>
        <Button Content="Open"/>
    </wpf:ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>

</Window>
```

Comment: It works, the overflow area  has the new Background now. The Overflow button is still ugly baby blue though. I guess I still have to Change the whole template.

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is good. Another way to modify the color of the OverflowButton and OverflowPanel is to modify them in the loaded event.

XAML

```
<ToolBar Loaded="ToolBar_Loaded">
```

Code behind:

```
private void ToolBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolBar toolBar = sender as ToolBar;
    var overflowGrid = toolBar.Template.FindName("OverflowGrid", toolBar) as Grid;
    if (overflowGrid != null)
    {
        overflowGrid.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }

    var overflowButton = toolBar.Template.FindName("OverflowButton", toolBar) as ToggleButton;
    if (overflowButton != null)
    {
        overflowButton.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }

    var overflowPanel = toolBar.Template.FindName("PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel", toolBar) as ToolBarOverflowPanel;
    if (overflowPanel != null)
    {
        overflowPanel.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

The names (OverflowGrid, OverflowButton, and PART_ToolBarOverflowPanel) can be found in the default control template, which could be downloaded from WPF's GitHub page.